# Under what assumptions can one compute conditional probability as $p(x)/p(y)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, definition, conditional-probability

Conditional probability is often introduced in the following way:

Consider a normal, fair 6-sided die. If you toss it then the probability $p(x=2)=1/6$. Now given that we already observed that the result is even, the probability $p(x=2|y=even)=1/3$, where it is obtained by $$\frac{p(x)}{p(y)}$$

Now later in the formal definition of conditional probability, it states that
$$
p(x|y)=\frac{p(x,y)}{p(y)}$$

My question is:
Under what assumptions can you swap $p(x,y)$ with $p(x)$ in the numerator?

Comment: your statement is unclear. where did $y$ come from? $p(x,y)$ is a joint probability and the nearest thing to your question is when we can appeal to independence i.e. $p(x)p(y)$. The only time it is equal to $p(x)$ is when there is no dependence on $y$ in the joint distribution. But clear up what you mean by $y$ in the second paragraph first :).

Comment: When x is a subset of y then $p(x,y)=p(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here notice that $X\cap Y=X$ because $X\subset Y$ since $2$ is even. So generally when events $A$ and $B$ and $A\subseteq B$ then we have $P(A\cap B)=P(A)$.

Also since $P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)P(B)$ so if $P(A|B)=1$ you have $P(A\cap B)=P(B)$ but also $P(A|B)=1$ will generally be true when $A\subseteq B$

Comment: you mean when events A and B and A⊆B then we have P(A∩B)=P(A)?

Comment: yep. that is correct, its because if $A\subseteq B$ then $A\cap B=A$

Comment: Can u edit the answer since it's different than what u mean.

Comment: Wanted to clarify that actually $P(A\cap B)=P(B)$ does not imply that $A\subseteq B$ it actually implies $P(A^c\cap B)=0$